# Swift 5 store event until all of the app has initialised

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, swift5

Im working on an Ionic/Capacitor native plugin in Swift

I am trying to integrate OneSignal push notification service, my code below works just fine if the app is in the foreground and a user clicks the notification, however if the app is started from clicking a notification my events dont fire, I figure this is because the `AppDelegate.swift` loads before Capacitor/Ionic and when my `NotificationCenter.default.post` gets fired the data doesnt reach my plugin.

I guess I want to know if there is any way in Swift to store this post data until all parts of the app have loaded and initialised i.e Capacitor/Ionics webview

AppDelegate.swift

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        let notificationOpenedBlock: OSHandleNotificationActionBlock = { result in
           // This block gets called when the user reacts to a notification received
           let payload: OSNotificationPayload = result!.notification.payload

           var fullMessage = payload.body

            let nc = NotificationCenter.default
                nc.post(name: Notification.Name("TestingEvents"), object: nil)

           if payload.additionalData != nil {
              if payload.title != nil {
                 let messageTitle = payload.title
                    print("Message Title = \(messageTitle!)")
              }

              let additionalData = payload.additionalData
              if additionalData?["actionSelected"] != nil {
                 fullMessage = fullMessage! + "\nPressed ButtonID: \(additionalData!["actionSelected"])"
              }
           }
        }


    return true
  }
```

MyPlugin.swift

```
    public override func load() {
        let nc = NotificationCenter.default
            nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleSignal), name: Notification.Name("TestingEvents"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func handleSignal() {
        self.bridge.triggerWindowJSEvent(eventName: "myCustomEvent")
        self.notifyListeners("myPluginEvent", data: [:])
    }
```

and my app.component.ts

```
      window.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', () => {
        alert("myCustomEvent ")
      });            
      Plugins.myPlugin.addListener("myPluginEvent", () => {
        alert("myPluginEvent ")
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a logical problem. 
 what you can do here is save the notificaiton data **(OSNotificationPayload)** in an object/dictionary/array you receive in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** and add an observer **"HandleNotificaionAfterPluginSetup"** to **appdelegate**.
For this observer, you can trigger a post notification from your plugin once it is initialized and have everything ready to handle notificaitons. 
 once you are all set in your plugin and have triggered the notificaion that code can execute in the notificaion handler you just setup which willl execute the code

````
              if payload.title != nil {
                 let messageTitle = payload.title
                    print("Message Title = \(messageTitle!)")
              }
              let additionalData = payload.additionalData
              if additionalData?["actionSelected"] != nil {
                 fullMessage = fullMessage! + "\nPressed ButtonID: \(additionalData!["actionSelected"])"
              }
           }```
````